# Wordpress. Отключить привязку изображений к посту

Tags: wordpress

Версия `Wordpress 6.1.1` . До этого такой проблемы не было. Сейчас не могу нигде найти ничего подобного. Все картинки автоматически подвязываются к посту, куда были загружены, надо только вручную их отвязывать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать это? Нужно, чтобы картинки были доступны везде.

Answer (score 0):

> До этого такой проблемы не было.

Всегда так было, но нет никакой проблемы и сейчас.

> Нужно, чтобы картинки были доступны везде.

Они и так "доступны везде". Если это не так - причина в другом.